# c error: expected expression before ‘{’ token

Tags: c, linux, expression, mutex

I must to write a program with table of mutexes. This code works on cygwin, but it don't work on linux. I don't understand, why it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.
Error:

```
pub.c:16:15: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
```

Code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pthread_mutex_t* mutex;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    mutex = malloc(n*sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mutex[i] = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; // <-- Error
    }

    free(mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use pthread_mutex_init instead of PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER here

```
pthread_mutex_init ( &(mutex[i]), NULL);
```

The PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER macro initializes the static mutex mutex, setting its attributes to default values. This macro should only be used for static mutexes, as no error checking is performed.